# Enabe System Restore and adjust Disc Space Usage to 5% via registry or command line

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

Exactly like the screenshot but via Registry or command line instead of GUI.

[image]

Comment: Check out https://www.windows-commandline.com/enable-disable-system-restore-service/ for the enabling portion at least. Give it a whirl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To enable system protection for a drive:

`powershell -command "Enable-ComputerRestore -Drive C:"`

### To set maximal allowed disk space:

`vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=10GB`

**Tip:** You can also use `/maxsize=5%` for percentual sizes and `/maxsize=UNBOUNDED` for unlimited size

**Both commands need to be executed as administrator.**

Comment: @Yethat In batch scripts you need to escape the `%` sign with `%%`, but not directly in cmd (I know this behavior is quite confusing...).